# Extreme noise with portals indoors

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, noise-reduction

my renders always turn out to have a lot of noise when indoors, what should i change?[image]

i know the samples are low, but no matter how high i set them, there is a lot of noise. Should i use the clamping settings? light bounces? i don't know how to mess with them yet.

Comment: Hello :). Just guessing. Light portals sometimes increase noise - do they help here? 2000-3000 samples is nothing unusual for indoor scenes. Bad HDRi can also be at fault. And are you using a *Denoiser*?

Comment: @JachymMichal not using denoiser because it makes the image lose way to much detail at the default settings. i thought there were other ways to fix this without increased samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.0 Materials with emission shaders can be configured to use Multiple Importance Sampling (Material Settings). This means that they will get rays sent directly towards them, rather than ending up there based on rays randomly bouncing around. For very bright mesh light sources, this can reduce noise significantly. Materials settings ==>: [image]

1.1. Multiple Importance Sample- enabling this will sample the background texture such that lighter parts are favored, creating an importance map. It will produce less noise in the render in trade of artifacts (fireflies). It is almost always a good idea to enable this when using an image texture to light the scene, otherwise noise can take a very long time to converge ==> World Settings:

[image]

2. Also important is to use shader colors that do not have components of value 1.0 or values near that; try to keep the maximum value to 0.8 or less and make your lights brighter.
3. Caustics are a well-known source of noise, causing fireflies,  There is a "No Caustics" option to disable glossy behind a diffuse reflection entirely(Properties -> Render -> Light Paths -> Caustics)